# Dojo Memory Store Periodic Refresh

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a dojo method to make an xhrRequest to get the latest list of items from DB and i do it periodically using `setInterval()`. Is there any other better way without using `setInterval()` that would automatically update the Memory store whenever a new item is added to the DB?.. The current code is below

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojo/store/Memory"
             data-dojo-id="dataStore">
            <script type="dojo/method">  
var myStore = this;
setInterval(function(){ 
require(["dojo/request/xhr"], function(xhr){
  xhr("myurl", {
    handleAs: "json"
  }).then(function(data){
if (data && data.length > 0) {   
                        myStore.setData(data);
                        }
  }, function(err){
    // Handle the error condition
  }, function(evt){
    // Handle a progress event from the request if the
    // browser supports XHR2
  });
});
}, 2000);                  
            </script>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use `dojo/store/JsonRest` in stead of `dojo/store/Memory`. If you really need the information to be up to date, then you should probably call `"myurl"` each time you want to fetch data, so that you don't have to poll the server for changes.

If you don't have a RESTful API, and you're not willing to implement your own `dojo/store` store (which could be a possibility as well), then you might want to look into WebSockets.

The problem about your approach is that it's quite network consuming (certainly if there are many clients). It would make a lot more sense if the server could push messages to the client, saying that the database changed and that they have to change their store.

This is a similar approach to how platforms like Meteor work, they sync serverside databases (partly) to clientside stores using WebSockets.

However, not all browsers support WebSockets ([caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=websockets)), but most frameworks provide a server+clientside component that can use the same fallback (long polling for example).

Take a look at the [Real-time Stores](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/realtime_stores/) article, which explains it a bit further into detail.

Comment: Yes the problem with Web sockets is that it's not supported in IE9 whereas this application specifically needs to be run on IE9. Will check the Real-time stores. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Real time stores are actually going further into detail on websockets, too bad :(. But like I said, most implementations of websockets (SockJS, Socket.io, ...) have fallback options using long polling or normal polling, so that it's actually kinda similar to your `setInterval()` except that it will work a lot better on browsers that do support websockets.

Comment: Oops okay.. guess i have no other option when it comes to IE9.